# Rails - how to get a path of uploaded file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm Trying to upload the csv using file_field tag in form. But I can't figure it out how to get the path of the file. Can anyone please help me...

form html page

```
<%= form_with(model: friend) do |form| %>
  <% if friend.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(friend.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this friend from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% friend.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.file_field :file, class:'form-control my-2' %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Submit' ,class: 'btn btn-secondary my-3' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

html file  --> show html file

```
<p>
    <strong>path:</strong>
    <%= @answer %>
  </p>
```

code in my controller --> show method

```
@answer = params[:file].path

Error: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
```

file I'm uploading its relative path is: 'D:/New folder/rails/work.csv'.

how am I supposed to get the path of an uploaded file after sending my app route to the show page.

Comment: my rails app all the necessary code... i post only related code which i think is necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: Your model is named friend so everything in the form is probably prefixed with something like params[:friend]. Perhaps you can add a raise params.inspect line to debug. Does it contain a params[friend][:file]? Than that is what you need.

Comment: ```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"friends", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"57"} permitted: false>
```
here is inspection of params

Comment: Ah ok you are rendering a show action not a create or update action. If you submit your form it would typically be posted to a create or update action based on your friend model. In your show action you are setting a non existing parameter. There is no file parameter in your params as we can see in your output. Are you being redirected to the show action after a create or update action?

Comment: actually, I'm creating a new Record and after submitting the records, rails showing me the the details of the record in show HTML page

Comment: Can you add the controller code, specificly the create and show actions?

Comment: Ok, and in your who action do you have a @ friend instance variable set? In that case your @ friend variable might have a file property which you can access via @ friend. file.